# Switching multiple divs in ordered sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 divs with IDs

```
<div id="1" class="div">1</div>
<div id="2" class="div">2</div>
<div id="3" class="div">3</div>
<div id="4" class="div">4</div>
<div id="5" class="div">5</div>
```

I need to cycle trough them 1 by 1, so there's only one div displayed at a time.
I tried to achieve that via this script:

```
$('#1').show();
$('#2').hide();
$('#3').hide();
$('#4').hide();
$('#5').hide();
function toggleAreas() {
  $("#1, #2, #3, #4, #5").toggle();    
}
$(document).ready(function(){    
  setInterval(toggleAreas, 2000);
});
```

It's a good way to switch between two divs, but doesn't work with multiple numbers. Instead of having only one div displayed and changing (1 then another, and then another and so on), now I have sequence of 1 div - 4 divs. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('#1').show();
$('#2').hide();
$('#3').hide();
$('#4').hide();
$('#5').hide();

function toggleAreas() {
  $("#1, #2, #3, #4, #5").toggle();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(toggleAreas, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="div">1</div>
<div id="2" class="div">2</div>
<div id="3" class="div">3</div>
<div id="4" class="div">4</div>
<div id="5" class="div">5</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the first visible `div` using the [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), hide it, and then select the next sibling element and show it:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zp1602fL/)

```
function toggleAreas() {
  var $hide = $('.toggle-areas > div:visible').hide();

  if ($hide.next().length) {
    $hide.next().show();
  } else {
    $hide.prevAll().last().show();
  }
}
```

```js
$('.toggle-areas > div:first').show().nextAll().hide();

function toggleAreas() {
  var $hide = $('.toggle-areas > div:visible').hide();

  if ($hide.next().length) {
    $hide.next().show();
  } else {
    $hide.prevAll().last().show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(toggleAreas, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle-areas">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm playing around with your solution and I got one follow up question - what should I do to either fadeIn or fadeOut div on every cycle? Everything I tried till now caused all divs to display at the same time.

Comment: @roonroon Rather than using the `.hide()` method, replace it with `fadeOut()`, and then fade the other elements in **inside** of the `fadeOut` callback - http://jsfiddle.net/4gc1qmzo/